# XcodeのInitialization of immutable value 'hogehoge' was never usedという警告を、とある行だけ消すには?

Tags: swift, xcode

CombineのPublisherのテストで、以下のような警告が出ています。

`Initialization of immutable value 'cancelable' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it`

この警告を（特定の行だけ）抑制する方法はありませんでしょうか?

SwiftLintをはじめとしたLintには行やファイルを指定して特定の警告を無視する手段がありますよね。Xcodeでも同様のものがあればいいなと期待して調べましたが、調べた範囲では見つけられませんでした。

Xcodeのアドバイス通りに`_`にアサインするとテストが壊れるため（即座に購読がキャンセルされてしまう）`cancelable`と名前をつけ、テストが終わるまで保持しています。

検討した解決策:

- テストのインスタンスのプロパティとして保持する方法→不要な情報をテスト後まで保持しておくのは構造が汚いように感じてやめました。
- LLVMの設定を変えて警告が出ないようにする方法→基本的に警告は出て欲しい（問題ないと確認できたものだけ見えないようにしたい）ので採用できません。
- `var cancelable` とする→`Initialization of variable 'cancelable' was never used`というほぼ同じエラーが出る。そりゃそうだ。
- テストの最後で`cancelable.cancel()`を呼ぶ→変な行が増えるので気持ち悪いが現状これを採用している

Comment: 「ツールは警告するが問題ない」ことを「プログラマの責任で保証する」のであれば逸脱を選択してそのことをコメントで残すだけです。警告を消すために無駄な努力をする＝人間がツールに使われている、ってことなので本末転倒。逸脱する手続きが無いってことならその辺の整備が先。

Comment: @774RR 「警告を消すために無駄な努力をする」状態であるかどうか、という質問です。

Answer (score 0):

Cancellableの`store(in:)`メソッドを使えばいいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: `cancellable.store(in: &disposeBag)`という感じでしょうか?

`cancellable.cancel()`とあまり変わらないような...

Comment: Cancellableを変数に入れずにメソッドチェーンでstore(in:)を使うということです。